# PHP Form is not processing endless loop

Tags: php

I have plus icon next to an input field in my form to so I can add more input fields. Name of the fields are automatically generated to in this form -> "one_f1", "one_f2" ...

When I create the mail to send it out, I need to create a while loop for this so I can put all the values that are sent from the form.

As soon as I added this code, my php form started taking too long to send the mail and that is causing this error;
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 267911134 bytes) in /mail/send.php on line 5

My code is;

```
$k = 0;
  while(isset($_POST["one_f".$k])){
     $body .= '<li style="list-style: circle;">'.$_POST["one_f".$k].'</li>';
  }
$k++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the "$k++" into the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
so I can put all the values that are sent from the form.
```

In php inorder to pull out all the values use `foreach`

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
//Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, I already used while because we don't know how many variables are going to be sent from the form. I forgot most of my PHP knowledge ahh:/ thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$k = 0;
while(isset($_POST["one_f".$k])){
 $body .= '<li style="list-style: circle;">'.$_POST["one_f".$k].'</li>';
 $k++;
}
```

$k++; should be into the loop